# Is it possible to add listboxitems from bottom in a listbox in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, listboxitem, delphi-xe7

I want to add listbox items from bottom and when I add more the first one scrolls up in the listbox. So it's reverse of adding items normally to a listbox.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly all you want is to add auto scrolling to the list box so that the last item is always visible? If that is so after ading the last item simply go and select it. This should scroll the view down.

Comment: @SilverWarior no, its not about auto scrolling. I want to know how to add the items from the bottom up, instead of from the top.

Comment: So you want the first item to be on the bottom, second above it, and so on?

Comment: First at the bottom, second below that and so on. The first item must go up after adding another item.

Comment: Ok I understand now what you want. The only solution or should I say workaround to do this with the ListBox that I can think of would be adding emptx listox items to fill the Listbox and thus move your first item downard. But if you do decide to go this way you would have to override ListBox default method for item selection and item Indexing so that those empty items won't interfere with normal handling. Anywhay this is quite ugly solution and could cause aditional problems. So perhaps serching for some other component might be bettwer way.

Answer (score 3):

Use the TStrings `Insert` or `InsertObject` methods with an index of `0` :

```
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0,'New Item');
```

Comment: But make sure to test for empty list in order to Add the first one, like this:
IF ListBox1.Items.Count=0 THEN ListBox1.Items.Add('1st item') ELSE ListBox1.Items.Insert(0,'New item - at top'); as I don't think you can INSERT into an empty list (correct me, if I'm wrong)

Comment: I think this question asks not how to insert item to the first position, but how to actually flip the list box (so that the first added item appear at the bottom of the list).

Comment: @HeartWare No problem inserting into `0` for an empty list.

Comment: @TLama  Ah, could be.  I don't think there's an easy solution to that other than custom painting...

Comment: @TLama, Yes I mean how to flip the listbox. I want items to appear at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

TListBox is probably the wrong place to start with this. Instead use a TScrollBox. Add your items as children. Each time you add an item recalculate the Position.Y of each item based on the Height of items after (below) it.

(Rethinking): actually it may be possible with TListBox if, again, after every insertion you recalculate positions and call ScrollBy.